# How can i turn the monaco editor into a react component using my own language definition (js file) (require is not defined...)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, monaco-editor

I am working on a monaco editor with my own language definition (mylang, it's a js file). Frontend is working with HTML. note: the editor has to be compatible with react (maybe its not even necessary to implement the editor as a react component?)

turning the monaco editor into a react component works, but as soon as i link the language definition file to the editor, it stops working and i get the require is not defined error and if i do it without the require function it doesnt recognize the editor anymore.

```
<!-- load language, somehow its not working with our language definition (mylang.js). there is a problem with the require command in mylang -->
<!-- in this file the monaco editors language is javascript (see line 34)  -->


<script src="./mylang.js"></script>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React Monaco Editor Example</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.25.2/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
      // Define a React component that uses the Monaco editor
      class MonacoEditor extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          this.state = {
            editorValue: "",
          };

          // Load the Monaco editor
          require.config({ paths: { vs: "https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.25.2/min/vs" } });
          require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], () => {
            // Initialize the editor
            const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
              value: "",
              language: "mylang",
              lineNumbers: false
            });
          });
        }
        
        render() {
        return React.createElement(
        'div',
        null,
        React.createElement('div', { id: 'container', style: { height: '400px', width: '800px' } }),
        React.createElement('pre', null, this.state.editorValue)
        );
        }
        
      }

      // Render the MonacoEditor component to the root element
      ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MonacoEditor, null), document.getElementById("root"));    
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the beginning of my language definition file:

```
require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
    // Define the language
    monaco.languages.register({ id: 'mylang' });
    
    // Define the list of keywords
    const mylangKeywords = [
      'continue', 'for', 'and', 'or',....
```